# Does sfdx-lwc-jest support the TAP or JUnit test result format that CI servers can consume?

Tags: unit-test, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

As far as I can see, the [salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest](https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest) LWC JavaScript test framework does not support the simple TAP ([Test Anything Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol)) output format that CI (Continuous Integration) servers such as Jenkins can easily consume and merge into their overall summary of test results.

(I've posted a request for this format here https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/issues/128.)

By the way, the formats are close e.g. TAP:

```
1..2
ok 1 - Input file opened
not ok 2 - First line of the input valid
```

and sfdx-lwc-jest output:

```
PASS force-app/main/default/lwc/progress/__tests__/progress.base.test.js
FAIL force-app/main/default/lwc/baseStep/__tests__/baseStep.test.js
```

Or is there **some hidden way to configure** that output format before I start writing a `sed` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Got a super quick answer here:

https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest/issues/128

to use:

https://github.com/MailOnline/jest-tap-reporter

I couldn't get it to work just configuring in `package.json` but this did work:

```
"scripts": {
    "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest -- --reporters='jest-tap-reporter'"
},
```

On reflection I'm going to use the JUnit format via https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-junit. So in `package.json':

```
"scripts": {
    "test:unit": "sfdx-lwc-jest -- --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit"
}
```

and then to run (inside https://claimvantage.github.io/sfdx-jenkins-shared-library/ but basically wrapped shell commands):

```
afterTestStage: {  org ->

    echo "${org.name} running LWC tests"

    // Install LWC test runner and JUnit reporter; config is in package.json and perhaps dependency should be too
    shWithStatus "npm install @salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest --save-dev"
    shWithStatus "npm install jest-junit --save-dev"

    // Test result folder
    sh "mkdir -p ${env.WORKSPACE}/tests/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/${org.name}"

    // Run tests - deliberately no status check so build doesn't fail immediately; klunky reporter option passing via environment variables
    sh returnStatus: true, script: "JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT_DIR='${env.WORKSPACE}/tests/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/${org.name}' JEST_JUNIT_OUTPUT_NAME='test-result-lwc-junit.xml' npm run test:unit"

    // Prefix class name with target org to separate the test results
    sh returnStatus: true, script: "sed -i -- 's/classname=\"/classname=\"${org.name}./g' ${env.WORKSPACE}/tests/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}/${org.name}/test-result-lwc-junit.xml/"
}
```